# Trying to import the selected text file to Cell A1

Tags: excel, vba, text, import, filedialog

I am trying to make a macro where I prompt the user to select a text file, and then have the contents of the selected text file imported to a cell. I managed to get the filedialog and have the user select the file, but then I don't know how to proceed with the importing of the file. Could someone help with this?

This is the (working) code I have so far:

```
 Sub ImportFile()
Dim dFile As FileDialog, result As Integer, it As Variant
Set dFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

dFile.InitialFileName = "G:\"


If dFile.Show = -1 Then
  Debug.Print dFile.SelectedItems(1)
End If


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to place the whole contents of a file in a single _cell_?? Is the file multi-line?

Comment: Anyway, look for the `Open` statement in Help. Then get the contents into a variable (lookup `Line Input`), then put the variable in the cell with `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = myVar` Replace 1,1 with the cell's coordinates.

Comment: Yeah it's a text file with a bunch of lines, trying to import it as delimited text separated into columns by space.  What do you mean by Open statement?

Comment: Please provide an example of the data, e.g. two lines.

Comment: Таблица: "FM_USER" Операция: "I" Пользователь: "AF12345" Дата: "30/06/2017 09:56:11"
 Поле: "USER_ID" Старое значение: "" Новое значение: "AC23572"
 Поле: "USER_INACTIVITY_DROP" Старое значение: "" Новое значение: "Y"
 Поле: "USER_LEVEL" Старое значение: "" Новое значение: "1"

Comment: Basically the text file is a bunch of this repeating a few hundred times over time with a header. I am trying to write a macro to import, format and decipher a Russian security report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are after something like the code below, it will import your entire .txt. file, to a 2-d array. Afterwards, you need to loop through the rows dimension, and copy each row's columns into your worksheet, starting from row 1.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportFile()

Dim fNum As Integer
Dim WholeFile As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim Arr As Variant, ArrRow As Variant
Dim i As Long, Col As Long

Dim dFile As FileDialog, result As Integer, it As Variant

Set dFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
dFile.InitialFileName = "G:\"

If dFile.Show = -1 Then
    FileName = dFile.SelectedItems(1)
End If

fNum = FreeFile
Open FileName For Input As fNum
WholeFile = Input$(LOF(fNum), #fNum)
Close fNum

Arr = Split(WholeFile, vbCrLf) ' Break the file into lines (array) change vbCrLf to your rows delimeter

' loop through Array rows
For i = 0 To UBound(Arr) - 1
    ArrRow = Split(Arr(i), ",")   '  break the row to columns , change "," to your delimeter
    Range("A" & i + 1).Resize(1, UBound(ArrRow)).Value = ArrRow
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If Space is the delimiter then do I put " " or ""? Also do I need to give the exact number of rows at vbCrLf? Because the number of potential rows is random.

Comment: @Rhyfelwr if it's Space the `" "`. And no, you don't need to give the exact number of rows, that's what nice about it, it's dynamic. Let me know if it works as you intended

Comment: Hello, quick question how do I define tab as a delimiter in this code? If I put `" |"` I get application or object defined error. Also at this line: `Range("A" & i + 1).Resize(1, UBound(ArrRow)).Value = ArrRow` should I put "A1" or something instead of A, as I get error 1004

Comment: Nvm I found that it is vbTab, I got the error because I didn't properly define the delimiter. Thanks for the help.